# Как в линуксе запускать команду по расписанию автоматически (мне нужно каждые 15 минут)?

Tags: linux, cron, cron-faq

Как в линуксе запускать команду по расписанию автоматически (мне нужно каждые 15 минут)?

Comment: Есть такая поделка период между командами нужно только в секундах указывать https://github.com/SidorkinAlex/bashCommandCyclicRunner

Answer (score 26, accepted):

удобнее всего это делать с помощью *cron-задания*.

*cron-задания* хранятся отдельно для каждого пользователя (включая *root-а*), файл с такими заданиями называется *crontab* (*cron table*), каждая незакомментированная строка — отдельное задание.

чтобы отредактировать свой персональный *crontab*, пользователю надо выполнить команду:

```
$ crontab -e
```

---

допустим, вам необходимо каждые 15 минут выполнять `команда аргумент1 аргумент 2`. для этого добавьте в *crontab* строку:

```
*/15 * * * * команда аргумент1 аргумент2
```

первые пять полей относятся к регулярности запуска и означают: «каждые 15 **минут** каждый **час** каждый **день** каждого **месяца** в каждый **день недели**»

---

подробнее про этот файл можно почитать в справке:

```
$ man 5 crontab
```

о программе *crontab*:

```
$ man 1 crontab
```

и о демоне *cron*, который, собственно, и выполняет задания:

```
$ man cron
```

---

**напоминание**: некоторые реализации программы *cron* не поддерживают синтаксис `*/число`, и вместо `*/15` следует использовать более совместимое `0,15,30,45`. за уточнением обратитесь к упомянутой документации по формату файла *crontab* в вашей системе.

Comment: Не все реализации `crontab` поддерживают такой синтаксис . Для сохранения максимальной совместимости лучше использовать `0,15,30,45 * * * *`

Comment: спасибо, добавил оговорку, несмотря на то, что, насколько помню дискуссию на *ufo* по этому поводу — такие древние реализации в современных дистрибутивах *gnu/linux* по умолчанию не ставятся.

Answer (score 9):

В файле cron пишем следующую строку:

```
  0,15,30,45 * * * * /path/to/command
```

Где **/path/to/command** путь до скрипта, который нужно запускать
Что у вас рулит кроном зависит от дистрибутива. По-моему на Убунте команда для редактирования правил cron выглядит так:

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

Comment: судо не надо если задание можно выполнить без привелегий, то лучше чтоб оно без них выполнялось

Answer (score 3):

У Systemd есть такой юнит, как .timer. Можете попробовать с его помощью.