# Переход по сcылке каждую минуту

Tags: linux, http, debian

Есть дистрибутив *Debian*.

Нужно каждую минуту делать переход по *http*-ссылке.

Можно ли это сделать скриптом, или каким нибудь кодом на *Python* или *С++*?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы можете использовать wget или curl

Для wget достаточно в простейшем случае написать

```
wget http://example.com/address
```

А чтобы выполнялось ежеминутно, добавить это в cron. Точный способ зависит от дистрибутива, но обычно, это делается командой

```
crontab -e
```

После чего откроется редактор vi. Нужно будет

Нажать ins

Дописать строчку

```
* * * * * wget http://что-то_там
```

Нажать Esc

Набрать

```
:w
```

Enter

```
:q
```

После этого изменения в cron будут сохранены

Это тестовый вариант - вам на локальную почту будут прилетать результаты работы программы. Чтобы они не вылетали, отправьте вывод в /dev/null, как советуют ниже

```
* * * * * wget http://что-то_там>/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 7):

для выполняения *http*-запроса можно воспользоваться любым удобным *http*-клиентом.

наиболее популярны из них `curl` и `wget`.

для ежеминутного запуска можно дописать в [свой `crontab`-файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/434351/178576) строку вида:

```
* * * * * curl -s http://адр.ес >/dev/null 2>&1
```

или

```
* * * * * wget -qO - http://адр.ес >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

Также для перехода по ссылке можно использовать консольный браузер, например lynx
Установка:

```
apt-get install lynx-cur
```

В cron, после выполнения команды

```
crontab -u USERNAME -e
```

(где USERNAME - имя пользователя, под которым вы хотите запускать команду) добавить строку

```
* * * * * lynx -dump http://ya.ru >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Но это уже скорее извращённый вариант, проще использовать wget или curl.