# Как правильно создать cron задачу в ajenti

Tags: cron

Как в панели управления  [ajenti](http://ajenti.org/) правильно создать cron-задачу для запуска PHP скрипта, находящегося  в `/srv/maxwebserver/bonus.php`, каждую минуту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

судя по [этому](http://support.ajenti.org/topics/835-better-explanation-of-cron/) ответу:

> Ajenti's Cron plugin can only be used to edit "native" Cron tabs, located in /var/spool/cron/crontabs

следует использовать [«обычный» синтаксис](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/434351/178576). примерно так:

```
 * * * * * /путь/к/php /srv/maxwebserver/bonus.php
```

уточнить путь к программе *php* — обычно `/usr/bin/php`.