# Как запустить mono приложение через cron?

Tags: unix, cron, mono

На данный момент я запускаю скрипт ручками

```
cd /var/www/test
mono vopros.exe
```

Как в cron пихнуть это задание? ЧТобы каждые 5 часов запускался скрипт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

от имени того же пользователя, от которого вы запускали упомянутые команды, выполните:

```
$ crontab -e
```

откроется на редактирование файл `crontab` этого пользователя.

в нём добавьте строчку:

```
* */5 * * * cd /var/www/test && mono vopros.exe
```

---

ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, с напоминанием в конце [моего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/434351/178576) на аналогичный вопрос: [Как в линуксе запускать команду по расписанию автоматически (мне нужно каждые 15 минут)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/434344/178576)

Comment: Я бы написал скрипт-объекту /usr/bin/vopros и уже этот скрипт запускал бы из cron.

Comment: @hse5yzdx, при желании можно ещё сложнее «завернуть».