# Ubuntu: автоматический перезапуск сервиса каждые N-минут

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Имеется ubuntu 14.04 x64.
Проблема:

Необходимо перезапускать сервис (в моем случае service tor) каждые (например) 10 минут. При этом сам он никогда не падает и работает всегда. Но иногда просто перестает выдавать новые IP (лечится перезагрузкой: service tor restart)

Подскажите, как настроить авто-перезагрузку?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/434344/178576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Cron?*
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron
Попробуй этот.

`m h dom mon dow user    command
 17 *  *   *   *  root   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
 25 6  *   *   *  root   test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
 47 6  *   *   7  root   test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
 52 6  1   *   *  root   test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )`